# TypeError:Cannot read property 'id' of undefined - nodejs - Sequlize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bulkinsert

I'm trying to save multiple row into DB, but all the time getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Here is some code implementations:

DB insert calling level:

```
createsomething(req, res, module, next){
//...
       testQuery.testBulkInsert(model, persistable,
            function(result){

                if(result.error == ''){
                    for(i = 0; i < result.res.length; i++){
                        module.list.push(result.res[i].id);
                    }
                    next(module);
                } else {
                    console.log('error #&@{;$÷');
                    console.log(result.error);                        
                }                
            }
```

Db insert opration level:

```
 function testBulkInsert(model, values, next){   
    console.log(values);
     model.bulkCreate(values)
          .then(function(obj){
            let result = new ResponseClass();
            result.res = obj;
            next(result);

          })
          .catch(function(err){
            console.log('Error during create new row...', err);            
            let result = new ResponseClass();
            result.error = 'Error during create new row...';
            next(result);   
          });
  }
```

Response class:

```
function SQLResponse(){
    this.res    = '';
    this.error  = '';
}

module.exports = SQLResponse;
```

In the testBulkInsert function the console.log(values); result is fine, I get the objectes:

```
[
    {
        title: 'dfasfa',
        url: 'fadfa',
        someOtherModelId: 18
    }, {
        title: 'fds',
        url: 'ghhgdj',
        someOtherModelId: 18
    }
]
```

And the model

```
var SomeModel= sequelize.define("SomeModel",
    {
          id : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
          title : {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
          url : {type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
        }
      );

      SomeModel.associate = function(models) {
        SomeModel.belongsTo(models.someOtherModelId, {foreignKey: {name:'someOtherModelId', allowNull:false}});
      }
```

Any idea?

------EDIT------

I get some strange behaviour: 
The process - in the testBulkInsert - do the "then" and the "catch" branch also. First time it saves -really, the objects presents in the db - the elements, and after it mooves into the catch branch and throw this error... I didn't call this method two time in the workflow....

Comment: Can you give us some details like : Where the error is throwed ? Which line ?

Comment: it looks the issue is here "  result.res = obj;"
probably "obj" is undefined then "module.list.push(result.res[i].id);" triggers the error

Comment: @Toodoo Error was throw in testBulkInsert operation. The line 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" 
came from here: 
"console.log('Error during create new row...', err);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the point: Just remove the for loop in createsomething method - this model dont need that process - , and actually I had some mistake also in an *if* statement in a code, what are nor referenced here. I fix these, and code run well. :)